# Is possibile to get the AST from a python code object?

Tags: python, compilation, abstract-syntax-tree, pyc

I know that's possible from a snippet of code in python to get its [AST](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=ast#ast.AST) or its [code object](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/code.html) via [compile()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html).

I was wondering if it is possible to do the opposite: I have the code object(extracted by a .pyc file) and I was looking for the its AST.

Comment: [astor](https://astor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), this may help

Answer (score 0):

The [third-party `astor` package](https://astor.readthedocs.io) provides a high-level functional API addressing this exact concern. Just pass the desired code object to the [`astor.code_to_ast()` function](https://astor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#astor.code_to_ast), which then decompiles that code object and returns the corresponding AST:

- `astor.code_to_ast(codeobj)`:

> Given a module, or a function that was compiled as part of a module, re-compile the module into an AST and extract the sub-AST for the function. Allow caching to reduce number of compiles.

Thanks to the [above two year-old comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67922884/is-possibile-to-get-the-ast-from-a-python-code-object#comment120056435_67922884) by @BoredRyuzaki for namedropping `astor`. You may be bored, Ryuzaki, but you have edified us all.

Answer (score -1):

No, unfortunately it is not possible to do by conventional methods unless the file that the code object created is still available in the path. There are tools like uncompyle6, which might help though.